# Play Videos in ASP.NET MVC using Custom Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to get Video using Custom action filter Below is the code which i find working but not able to pass strvideoFilePath as variable.This is my VideoCustomDataResult.cs Code

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {

            var strVideoFilePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/VideoFiles/Test2.mp4");

            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test2.mp4");

            var objFile = new FileInfo(strVideoFilePath);

            var stream = objFile.OpenRead();
            var objBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(objBytes, 0, (int)objFile.Length);
            context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(objBytes);

        }
```

Here i am calling it as

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return new VideoDataResult(FileUrl);
        }
```

Can Anyone tell me how to pass that video source as variable from razor view.

Comment: could you use a URL helper?

Comment: @DanielA.White Donot know how to use it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx